# Google Drive API on upload--where are these extra blank lines coming from?

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

To summarize the program: I'm downloading a file from my Google Drive, I'm then opening and reading a file("file_a.txt") in my local machine, then I'm opening another file in my machine("file_b.txt") in append mode, and I'm appending "file_a.txt" into "file_b.txt" before updating my Google Drive with this new "file_b".

For some reason I'm getting these blank lines. And they expand in a very peculiar way. Here's the final output of my program with the ghost lines:

```
==
***
name
































class
====
***
some new song
















class
====
***
final








class
====
***
final




class
====
***
final


class
====
***
final

class
==
```

See how with every new successive `python main.py` run, the gap between "name" and "class" of the *previous writes* gets wider and wider, top to bottom?
edit: there's a pattern to the blank lines. They are doubling. 2->4->8->16->32 in my files.

Here's my "file_a.txt" that I'm reading from:

```
==
***
name

class
==
```

There should only be one blank line..

"file_b.txt" is initially blank.

Now here's the python program that downloads and updates according to the Google Drive API:

```
drive_service = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=http)
file_id, name = search_file(drive_service, 10, "name contains 'test_file'")
print(file_id, name)

if verified_file(a, b):
    file_path = "file_b.txt"
    downloaded = download_file(drive_service, file_id, file_path)
    with open('file_a.txt', 'r') as myfile:
        data = myfile.read()
    with open("file_b.txt", "a+") as myfile:
        myfile.seek(0, 2)

        myfile.write(data)

    path_of_new_file = "file_b.txt" # the file to upload
    file_name_on_drive = "test_file" # the name to upload as
    if file_id:
        update_file(drive_service, file_id, path_of_new_file, file_name_on_drive)
```

Where are these blank lines coming from?

edit: does it have anything to do with the mimetype?
In both my download, and upload, they are being targeted as `'text/plain'`:

```
def download_file(service, file_id, filepath):
    request = service.files().export_media(fileId=file_id, mimeType='text/plain')
    fh = io.BytesIO()
    downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
    done = False
    while done is False:
        status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
        print("Download %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100))
    with io.open(filepath,'wb') as f:
        fh.seek(0)
        f.write(fh.read())  

def update_file(service, file_id, path_of_new_file, file_name_on_drive):
    mimetype = 'text/plain'
    file_metadata = {'name': file_name_on_drive}
    media = MediaFileUpload(path_of_new_file,
                            mimetype=mimetype)
    file = service.files().update(fileId=file_id,
                                  body=file_metadata,
                                  media_body=media).execute()
    print('File ID: %s' % file.get('id'))
```

**Edit:**

Something tells me newlines aren't the issue either:

Here's how I updated the code to strip newlines:

```
with open('file_a.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    data = myfile.readlines()
    print("data,", data)

with open("file_b.txt", "a+", newline='') as f:
    readfile = f.readlines()

    print("read", readfile)

    list2 = [a for a in readfile if a != '\n']
    print("newread", list2)

    list2.extend(data)

    print("2", list2)
    for item in list2:
        f.write(item)

path_of_new_file = "file_b.txt" # the file to upload
file_name_on_drive = "test_file" # the name to upload as
if file_id:
    update_file(drive_service, file_id, path_of_new_file, file_name_on_drive)
```

And Command line output during run to prove there arent rogue newlines right before updating:

```
Download 100%.
data, ['==\n', '***\n', 'final\n', '\n', 'class\n', '==']
read []
newread []
2 ['==\n', '***\n', 'final\n', '\n', 'class\n', '==']
```

and still on my google drive, there will be blank lines that get wider with every update.

Comment: Google docs adds two new lines after each paragraph. You need to remove the ones that are there before upload it again or its going to add two new ones.

Comment: Okay. So there is essentially no way for me to update(download, append contents of new text file, then upload) documents on GD with a text file that includes its own newlines, without the format being messed up?

Comment: Do you know how to input single blank lines into a repeatedly updated google doc?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where and how do I strip the blank lines created by google docs on the Drive API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49625386/where-and-how-do-i-strip-the-blank-lines-created-by-google-docs-on-the-drive-api)

Comment: Please stop opening new questions asking the same thing stick with one and improve it. stackoverflow.com/q/49622725/1841839 stackoverflow.com/q/49625386/1841839 stackoverflow.com/q/49627579/1841839